# Skip/Ignore values from an array matlab

Tags: matlab

Given the following array `[123 1 123 2 122 1 123 124]` How can I quickly recreate an array which keeps the same order but skips values `1` & `2`?

I'm pretty sure it's simple but I am at a loss there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html), you can maintain the original order and keep repetitions:

```
skipVals = [1 2];
x = [123 1 123 2 122 1 123 124];
y = x(~ismember(x,skipVals))

y =
   123   123   122   123   124
```

And because I know Luis Mendo will suggest this, and I feel like being wicked:

```
y = x(all(bsxfun(@ne,x,skipVals.'),1))
```

Comment: +1 But I'm a bit disappointed. Where's your `accumarray` solution??

Comment: Damn! It seems like my array is a a {} with strings in it. How could I first convert that array into integers? In an easy way? I've just googled and all sorts of really long implementations come up

Comment: @Bastien The numbers are actually strings?  Try `str2num`. What's an example string?

Comment: @Bastien You can use the same approach with cell arrays of strings: `result = strings(~ismember(strings,skipStrings))`

Comment: Thanks Luis. I actually ended up assign the following values to skipVals: ``{'1' '2'}`` but I guess your suggestion would work too and looks more elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
    a=[123 1 123 2 122 1 123 124];
    b=a;
    b(b==1)=[];b(b==2)=[];
```

Comment: Thanks! That's also helpful.